# how to get an object inside an array with a value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array looks list :

```
[
   {
      "Name":"S",
      "Level":"1",
      "Uid":"huybd776",
      "isHuman":false
   },
   {
      "Name":"R",
      "Level":"35",
      "Uid":"673bjhbjhdcsy",
      "isHuman":true
   }
]
```

I have a value i.e Uid `673bjhbjhdcsy`, how do I check if that Uid exists in the array and get the whole object associated with the Uid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
result = [
   {
      "Name":"S",
      "Level":"1",
      "Uid":"huybd776",
      "isHuman":false
   },
   {
      "Name":"R",
      "Level":"35",
      "Uid":"673bjhbjhdcsy",
      "isHuman":true
   }
].find(item => item.Uid === '673bjhbjhdcsy')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` like:

```js
const data = [
   {
      "Name":"S",
      "Level":"1",
      "Uid":"huybd776",
      "isHuman":false
   },
   {
      "Name":"R",
      "Level":"35",
      "Uid":"673bjhbjhdcsy",
      "isHuman":true
   }
];

console.log(data.find(x => x.Uid === '673bjhbjhdcsy'));
```

Reference:

- [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?retiredLocale=en)